# unable to connect to hbase using java(in Eclipse) in Cloudera VM

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to connect to Hbase using Java(in Eclipse) in Cloudera VM, but getting below error. Am able to run same program in command line(by converting my program into jar)

my java program

```
    `import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
    //import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
   public class HbaseConnection {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.addResource("/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml");
        HTable table = new HTable(config, "test_table");
        byte[] columnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("colf");
        byte[] idColumnName = Bytes.toBytes("id");
        byte[] groupIdColumnName = Bytes.toBytes("g_id");
        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("testkey"));
        put.add(columnFamily, idColumnName, Bytes.toBytes("test id"));
        put.add(columnFamily, groupIdColumnName, Bytes.toBytes("test group id"));
        table.put(put);
        table.close();

      }
    }`
```

And I have kept hbase-site.xml in the source folder in eclipse
hbase-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
    <value>8070</value>
    <description>The port for the HBase REST server.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.thrift.info.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>
```

And am getting below error while running the program in eclipse

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:150)
    at com.aig.gds.hadoop.platform.idgen.hbase.HBaseTest.main(HBaseTest.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:387)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:633)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecations([Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.addDeprecatedKeys(HdfsConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.<clinit>(HdfsConfiguration.java:31)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.<clinit>(DistributedFileSystem.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 26 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is in the stack trace:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecations
```

This means that your `hadoop-common-* jar` version is not in sync with your `hadoop-hdfs-* jar` version Or you may have a mix of different versions in your class path.

Note that addDeprecations is present in hadoop 2.3.0 and later :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html

but was missing in 2.2.0 and prior:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html